# How do I compose MCVE C++ question on stacks when code depends on multiple files?

Tags: support

I'm new to C++ and have a hard time determining what MCVE is when asking questions about stack. It seems that Stack Overflow are a lot stricter towards user asking question about C++ than other languages in general. Now specifically I just posted *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734317/why-does-count-variable-increment-with-one-if-statement-but-when-including-anot* and edited upon reading the guidelines when I got downvoted. The moderator still do not think this is an MCVE question.

Can anyone give an example of MCVE, when the code is composed of multiple files (i.e. both hpp and cpp files)?

Comment: c++ *does not* require multiple files - all code can be in single CPP file just fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> Streamline your example in one of two ways:
>
> 1. **Restart from scratch.** Create a new program, adding in only what is needed to see the problem. This can be faster for vast systems where you think you already know the source of the problem. Also useful if you can't post the original code publicly for legal or ethical reasons.
> 2. **Divide and conquer.** When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back.

I'd recommend #1 here. Start writing your routine from scratch. Initially, it won't do anything more than recurse until the threshold is reached, and then end. Now start adding stuff in, one *teeny-tiny piece* at a time, until you've managed to reproduce the problem.

I rather suspect that if you do this, the error in your program will stick out like a sore thumb and you won't bother asking the question at all. But, if you don't see it, you'll at least be posting a routine that's only about 5 lines long, and folks won't be complaining about excessive code.

Comment: How would this be if my code is working with dependencies from a code skeleton which is provided? Should this only be for the part I wrote? or should i Try to include parts som the provided part also?

Comment: You start by eliminating the dependencies, @Ptru. Your code should start as an empty shell - something like, `int minimax_val(int count) { count++; if (count == 3) return count; return minimax_val(count); } int main() { printf("minimax: %d", minimax_val(0)); return 0; }` Then you add bits of functionality and test data, just a little bit at a time, until the problem is recreated.

Comment: @Ptru - The goal is to make something "verifiable", and the important aspect of verifying behavior is that a user like myself can take the code without modifying it and verify the problem. Without that ability, there is no MCVE, and it is *very* hard to answer. This is why Shog is suggesting that you start small and build up a code example that can be used as opposed to the entirety of your existing application or section. It is important to keep in mind what it would be like to be someone that is trying to answer your question, and what they would need in order to help.

Comment: So in my case, it would be recreating the problem, as minimalistically as possible. I.e making a new recursion function that is not dependent on the provided dependencies and look at the behavior of the minimalistic function. Is this correct?

Comment: Right, @Ptru. Add dependencies one at a time: every piece of data, every function, add it only when you can't reproduce without it. So given what I see from your post, you might end up with a dummy `findPossibleMoves()` routine that just returns a pre-defined vector that triggers the behavior before you're able to reproduce the problem... Or it might show up before that, or you might find that your problem actually lies in findPossibleMoves() instead. The key here is breaking down the logic enough so that you can isolate the source of the issue.